# How to center an element within a parent div vertically

Tags: css, alignment

I want to center below `wrapper` inside the parent div element with a `height` equal to `windows` `view height`, using `CSS`.

HTML

```
<div class="main-header">
   <div class="wrapper">center div</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main-header{
color: #fff;
background: #16a8ec;
padding: 10px;
height: 100vh;
position: relative; }

.wrapper{
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
transform: translate(0px, 50%); /* i used transform but it doesn't work */
-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 50%); /* i used transform but it doesn't work */ }
```

Please help me guys, thanks.

Comment: The issue was solved with the use of display flex

Comment: @bellabelle Hi, try this way: https://jsfiddle.net/dh0o82g6/ with positioning && with flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/dh0o82g6/1/

Comment: Instead of using px in your positioning , try using `%` works perfect with different screens.

Answer (score 2):

**With flexbox :**

```
.main-header{
  color: #fff;
  background: #16a8ec;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  /* Flexbox */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; 
}

.wrapper{
  /* your wrapper style */
}
```

**With absolute position :**

```
.main-header{
  color: #fff;
  background: #16a8ec;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative; 
}

.wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: the result is not

Comment: Sorry, you're right with your answer, display flex then align-items center

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

**The changes:**

1. html and body element should be set to height of the window(viewport), so I used the property `height:100vh`, then body by default has the margin set to `8px`, so I used the property `margin:0px`.
2. To center the div inside you just need to use, `text-align: center` for the div with class `main-header`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}

.main-header {
  color: #fff;
  background: #16a8ec;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header">
  <div class="wrapper">center div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: no, i want to center the wrapper element vertically

Comment: @bellabelle can you check my answer now?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:  **Added `top:46%` and `left:46%`**, you can also do it other way around.

```css
.main-header{
color: #fff;
background: #16a8ec;
padding: 10px;
height: 100vh;
position: relative; }

.wrapper{
position: absolute;
top:46%;
left: 46%;
transform: translate(0px, 50%); /* i used transform but it doesn't work */
-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 50%); /* i used transform but it doesn't work */ }
```

```html
<div class="main-header">
   <div class="wrapper">center div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `top: 0; bottom: 0` to your `.wrapper` like this:

```css
.main-header{
color: #fff;
background: #16a8ec;
padding: 10px;
height: 100vh;
position: relative; }

.wrapper{
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
transform: translate(0px, 50%); /* i used transform but it doesn't work */
-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 50%); /* i used transform but it doesn't work */ 
text-align: center;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header">
   <div class="wrapper">center div</div>
</div>
```

You can also check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6svd6h2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just give `display: table` to parent and `display: table-cell; vertival-align: middle;` to child that will work for you.

Working example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .main-header {
            color: #fff;
            background: #16a8ec;
            padding: 10px;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            display: table;
        }
        
        .wrapper {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main-header">
        <div class="wrapper">center div</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```